# Soft. Keyboard Covers Edit Text AFTER Dismissed but Not BEFORE

Tags: android, keyboard, android-scrollview, android-relativelayout

When the app is first opened and I select my EditText, the software keyboard appears and the view scrolls up to make room for the keyboard—as it should. But once I dismiss the keyboard with the down arrow and then select the EditText again, the keyboard hides the EditText.

[image: View BEFORE Keyboard dismissed]
[image: View AFTER Keyboard dismissed]

I have already tried setting the activity to fullscreen, changing `RelativeLayout` to `ScrollView`, and setting `android:windowSoftInputMode` to `"adjust Pan"`.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="org.example.TheApp.LaunchActivity"
    android:background="#333333">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/prefixLL"
    android:weightSum="1">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/image_audio"
    android:layout_marginBottom="75dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:hint="@string/prefixHint"
    android:textColorHint="#EBEBEB"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/prefixTextField"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:autoText="false"
    android:imeOptions="actionGo"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:background="#5A595B"
    android:textColor="#F5F5F5"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:inputType="textVisiblePassword" />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```